# No request body recieved from api call

Tags: node.js, api, express, mern

This is my server.js -

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./api/config/db");
const feedbackRouter = require("./api/routes/feedbackRouter");

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

connectDB();

app.use(feedbackRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`SERVER IS LIVE AT ${PORT}`);
});
```

Router (feedbackRouter.js)-

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/feedback", (req, res) => {
  const feedbackData = req.body;
  try {
    console.log(feedbackData);
    res.send(feedbackData);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I make an API call from the frontend(React) or Postman, the `req.body` gives me undefined and I don't see the content from the request anywhere.

The API call gives me status code of 200 in Postman.

Any idea what might be wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mark it as an answered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add **app.use(express.json())** to your Code.

Server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const connectDB = require("./api/config/db");
const feedbackRouter = require("./api/routes/feedbackRouter");

const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(express.json())

connectDB();

app.use(feedbackRouter);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`SERVER IS LIVE AT ${PORT}`);
});
```

About express.json() method and its options:

> https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html

You didn't use any body-parsers, they use to process the body of an request, documentation:

> http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html

Postman Request & Response:
[image: Postman Screenshot]